# Abnormal crashes after a few minutes of gaming

Tags: kernel, games, freeze, crash

as I mentioned in the title on my gaming pc I am having serious problems in running games via Lutris. Playing on steam with proton doesn't cause any problem... The Issue comes once I run a game on Lutris, basically everygame... My computer freezes and I cannot do nothing except reboot by using the physical key on the PC case.
Here you can read the logs after the rebooting

```
15:11:27 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_cs_ioctl [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Failed to initialize parser -125!
15:11:27 kernel: amdgpu 0000:09:00.0: [drm:amdgpu_ring_test_helper [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring comp_1.1.0 test failed (-110)
15:11:26 kernel: amdgpu: rlc is busy, skip halt rlc
15:11:25 kernel: [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process GameMainThread pid 4248 thread dxvk-submit pid 4272
15:08:18 systemd: Failed to start Application launched by gnome-session-binary.
15:08:15 kernel: __common_interrupt: 10.55 No irq handler for vector
```

Really I dont know what to do.
Currently I am using 5.19 kernel and this looks to be a problem related with...AMD drivers? I dunno, that's why I am asking for help...

On [This link](https://freeimage.host/i/schermata-del-2023-07-03-15-15-38.HieTeAG) You can read the logs more in details and on [this youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgUugql6S74) you can see how the problem displays... Its not always like this, sometimes I get only a black screen too...

If need my syste spec are:

Mobo gigabyte gaming x

GPU XFX RX 590

Ryzen 3700x

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, kernel is 5.19 and I've latest mesa driver installed.
I also read that this kernel is causing problems, who can tell me something about?

Thank you for your help